# Using jquery, extract each group of adjacent siblings, matching selector, from a larger group of siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="special child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="special child"></div>
    <div class="special child"></div>
    <div class="special child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

What I need to do is extract 2 sub collections of `div.special` (for the 2 groups of adjacent siblings), then wrap each group with another parent, ending up with:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="special_parent">
        <div class="special child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="special_parent">
        <div class="special child"></div>
        <div class="special child"></div>
        <div class="special child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I could begin with iterating through the sibling elements and doing some heavy lifting, but I feel convinced there should be a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

```js
$('.special').each(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass('special_parent')) return
  $(this)
    .nextUntil(':not(.special)')
    .add(this)
    .wrapAll('<div class="special_parent">')
})
```

```css
.special_parent {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="special child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="special child">5</div>
  <div class="special child">6</div>
  <div class="special child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
  <div class="child">9</div>
  <div class="special child">10</div>
  <div class="special child">11</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @User863. Looks decent. Let me take a moment to check this out.